# Images appear loaded twice in instruments (iPhone + openframeworks)

Tags: iphone, image, load, instruments

I am programming for the iPhone using openFrameworks. I ran the project in the device with Instruments/System Usage and I saw that **ALL the images appear to be loaded twice**, even if I use them only once.

(see screen capture of Instruments here http://bit.ly/htoaNx )

I don't know if this could be a FreeImage problem or I am failing at interpreting the results?

Thanks!

Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that is telling you is that fopen and fclose are being called twice on the same file. The most likely explanation for that is that either FreeImage or openFrameworks checks to see if the file exists (fopen() then immediately fclose()) before actually loading the image. Another possibility is the file is opened to determine the format/bit depth/size, the file is closed, memory is allocated, then the file is re-opened and actual image data is read.